# Saving two tables in a form

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone point me to a decent tutorial?

What I want is submit a form with two tables in it, but my problem is the 1st table(`tbl_request`) has none yet a `RequestID` while it is needed in the second table(`tbl_conversation`).

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you submit the `Form` first you `insert` the values into `tbl_request`. and get the `inserted id` from that, after that insert it into `tbl_conversation` table with rest of your table data's.

Comment: can you give me a code for that? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inserting in `tbl_request` use

```
$id = mysql_insert_id(); //it will get last inserted id
```

After that insert this id to another table `tbl_conversation`

Answer (score 0):

On your insert form,

```
if($_POST['SERVER_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   // Insert into tbl_request
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_request(1, 2, 3, 'blah')");
   $tbl_request_id = mysql_insert_id();

   // Next you insert into tbl_conversation with reference of `$tbl_request_id`
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_conversation(1, $tbl_request_id , 3, 'blah')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a little example to make it a bit easier:

```
// Do your first query

mysql_query("INSERT INTO first_table (product) values ('Car')");

$id = mysql_insert_id();

// Do your second query here

mysql_query("INSERT INTO second_table (product, first_id) values ('Lamp', '".$id."')");
```